# How to reread/reiterate an external helper file using \@starttoc?

Tags: package-writing, auxiliary-files

I have the issue that I want to create a package/class that collects some data throughout the document processing. This data needs to be stored in a helper file to save for later runs.

I found that I can use `\@starttoc` to read a helper file and `\addcontents` to write to it.

I wrote a MWE to explain what I want to do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% This would be in a class/package
\newcommand{\task}[2]{Task num: #1 (#2 points)\addtocontents{tsk}{\protect\my@task{#1}{#2}}\par}
\newcommand{\printtasks}{\begin{itemize}\@starttoc{tsk}\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\my@task}[2]{\item Process task \textbf{#1} with #2 points.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\printtasks
\task{Foo}{2}
\task{Bar}{3}

% \printtasks % Uncomment to trigger issue
\task{Baz}{5}
\task{Foobar}{3}
\end{document}
```

I want to write some tasks in the document (exam) with points attached.
The exam wil consist of multiple sections with a summary of points per task on the start of each section.
The `\printtasks` should start such a section of the document.

The first occurence of `\printsection` should only show the tasks `Foo` and `Bar`.
This can be managed using additional parameters, a counter and some if-then-else magic.
I left it out of the MWE to keep it minimal.

The second (yet commented) occurence of `\printtasks` should print the tasks of the upcoming section (`Baz` and `Foobar`).
To do so, I need to reiterate over the helper `.tsk`-file.
(Without the filtering in the MWE of course all tasks should be visible.)
The newly called command to `\@starttoc` seems to not open the file again but detect it was opened before already.
Nothing is iterated as a result, rendering my approach non-functional.

I know I have seen packages to use a similar approach to the package `biblatex` where one can specify `refsection`s. Unfortunately, I am unable to understand all glory details of this huge package.

Comment: you can not at the same time read a file and write to it. As soon as you open it for writing it will be cleared. If you need the content twice store it e.g. in a command.

Comment: So, are you telling me I need to go with `openin`/`openout` and read/parse the file manually?